# Why is WPF not updating on INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` by implementing the same interfaces and passing calls to an `` ObservableCollection`1 ``:

```
class WrappedObservableCollection<TElement> : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged //, ...others
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TElement> BaseList;

    public WrappedObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<TElement> baseList)
    {
        Contract.Requires(baseList != null);

        this.BaseList = baseList;
    }

    #region wrapping of BaseList

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { ((INotifyPropertyChanged)BaseList).PropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { ((INotifyPropertyChanged)BaseList).PropertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This all works fine, but when I bind to the `.Count` property, the UI never updates.  I would suspect something is wrong with my implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I have verified that `PropertyChanged.add` is called, and that an event is raised when the property is being changed.

Comment: Is there any reason for delegation? Why not simply derive from ObservableCollection?

Comment: I didn't want to expose `IList` or other mutators - it is a read-only collection.

Comment: You know there is [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I did not.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the `.add` call to the internal list is insufficient as WPF uses the `sender` parameter of the event to determine which bindings need to be updated.  Use the following to wrap `INotifyPropertyChanged` while updating the `sender`:

```
class WrappedObservableCollection<TElement> : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged //, ...others
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TElement> BaseList;

    public WrappedObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<TElement> baseList)
    {
        Contract.Requires(baseList != null);

        this.BaseList = baseList;
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this.BaseList).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    #region wrapping of BaseList

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```